# No text in my UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

just created an UITableView,

trying to display some custom data from an array, but what ever I do, i get no text displayed.

NSLog tell me the right text and right amout but no text in table cell.

here is the code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = @"test";

    [self configureCell:cell atIndexPath:indexPath];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: is the `height` of the cell set properly?

Comment: What is textLabel? Have you connected it with your component defined in your xib?

Comment: please post the configureCell method, maybe the textLabel is modified there

Comment: this is a default master details project... cell.bounds.size.heighttell me 44px. textLabel must be a default method :)

Comment: try commenting out `[self configureCell:]` and see you get the 'test' to show up. If it does show up, then its the `configureCell:` method. You will need to post the code for that method.

Comment: @MarcoPace textLabel is the default title label for a UITableViewCell, it is automatically created.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things to check:

Is `cellForRowAtIndexPath` getting called? Put a breakpoint in

Make an array in ViewDidLoad (property, alloc'd) and `addObjects @"One", @"Two", @"Three", nil` and then `cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];`

If`cellForRow` is being called, this will show in the cells.
What does`ConfigureCell` do? Include the code please.

Also check your tableView delegate methods are being called (`NumberofRowsInSection` etc)

Comment: Yes it does, a get the NSLog, in this method

Comment: the line `cell.textLabel.text = ...` should be placed inside the configureCell method

Answer (score 0):

Always set cell properties (text, images, accessory views, etc) in the

```
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath
```

delegate method.

UITableView sometimes send a prepareForReuse to the cell after it is returned from

```
tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

which causes the cell to reset it's labels and images.